# Adview in listview not visible (android)

Tags: android, listview, adview

I am follow google's listview tutorial (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) and I'm trying to ad an adview to my listview (so that it always stays on top), but I can't get it working. I've tried relativelayout and linear but I can't get it working. I've tried replacing the adview with a button but the button doesn't show up either. Right now I'm using this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="bannerID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This code looks good in the graphical layout but when I run the app it gets covered by the textview in list_item.xml. Anyone have any idea how to get this working? Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change layout_height in ListView to wrap_content

Comment: tried changing to wrap_content but it doesn't work. Still gets covered by the text in list_items. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Do you declare com.google.ads.AdActivity in AndroidManifest.xml ? I think Button doesn't appears becouse of layout_height, try change it to wrap_content in ListView and add button.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
Tried doing that but the button still doesn't show up. And yes, adview is showing up in the other activities, so it's working

Comment: Ok, do you set  custom View by setContentView()? (ListActivity from hello-listview is using default layout, only list items). And your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list". Please take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) for more info about ListView, maybe it helps

Comment: I made my own layout with a listview with id "@android:id/list" and set the content view to that view and guess what? It WORKED! Thank you SO much, Style!! You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout_height to wrap_content instead of fill_parent

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. The screen still gets covered by the listview :(